# why React app tab favicon remains default even after replacing it

Tags: reactjs, favicon

I have replaced favicon.ico and logo192.png and logo512.png with custom logo but it remains the default react logo. Here's the website [rzees.com](https://www.rzees.com)

Answer (score 1):

It's cached. Try to reload with `Ctrl+Shift+R` command

Comment: Yup problem solved. thankss